# LocationListener how to stop when onLocationChanged() is called?

Tags: android, locationlistener

I want locationlistener to stop using gps when the location is changed, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

}
```

here **this** is the reference to LocationListener Interface.

If you want only single location update then you can call

**locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, Looper.getMainLooper());**